# ¿Como puedo obtener la duracion de un video usando mediainfo.dll? VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, video

Estoy probando mediainfo.dll pero noto que hay poca informacion por lo que busco dos cosas, primero un ejemplo de como obtener la duracion de un video y si tienen algun link con la documentación que me puedan compartir sobre mediainfo.dll.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza WMP.DLL la cual es el propio reproductor de windows multiformato el cual te dira la duraccion entre otros datos y podrás reproducirlo si quieres, se agrega como control de usuario por los Componentes COM.

Se agrega desde el menu de Controles pulsando el botón derecho del ratón, has de ir "Elegir elementos" una vez allí agregar "Windows Media Player" de la Sección de "Componentes COM" y una vez hecho esto cargar esta Function...

```
Public Function GetDuracionArchivo(ByVal FilePath As String) As String
    On Error Resume Next

    With AxWindowsMediaPlayer1
        .settings.autoStart = False
        .URL = FilePath
        '.Ctlcontrols.stop()
        GetDuracionArchivo = .currentMedia.durationString
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: On eror resume next es una muy mala idea (y antigua). Los errores no deben dejarse pasar porque si, hay que controlarlos segun corresponda con un try catch.